# Convert NSObject to NSDictionary JSON swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

I try to make a receive notification with JSON inside. so i code inside AppDelegate.swift. 
I have a problem with converting NSObject to NSDictionary.

Here is my code :

> ```
> func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
>         PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
> ```

```
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {

            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
            let msg = userInfo["test"] as? NSObject
            print(userInfo)

            if msg == nil{

                    let dict = msg as! Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>>>
                    let tests = dict["test"]!["test"]!
                    for test in tets {
                        let header : AnyObject? = test["message"]
                        let body : AnyObject? = test["aps"]
                        let url : AnyObject? = test["link"]

                        print("test ID: \(header)")
                        print("test Name: \(body)")
                        print("test Needs Password: \(url)")


                }
            }
        }
```

there are 2 problem :
1. i've already receive the JSON Data as Object
let msg = userInfo["test"] as? NSObject

```
Printing description of userInfo:
    ▿ 3 elements
      ▿ [0] : 2 elements
        - .0 : message
        - .1 : test iOS
      ▿ [1] : 2 elements
        - .0 : aps
        - .1 : 0 elements
      ▿ [2] : 2 elements
        - .0 : link
        - .1 :
```

But my msg is nil. so i have to do this code to continue if msg == nil

2. i don't know how to use NSJSONSerialization, because the error always showed " Cant convert NSObjet to NSData type"

Comment: Be more specific! The APNS payload is at least `Dictionary<String,AnyObject>`. Deserialization is not needed since `userInfo` contains already a Cocoa object.

Comment: @vadian so i can convert my object data to string without serialization ?

Comment: You should be casting the value of the value of the "test" key to whatever data type it is, as in a String or maybe even an NSNumber. As @vadian pointed out you're already dealing with an object in the userInfo dictionary so you just need to access the data and cast it appropriately.

Comment: Yes, start with `if let msg = userInfo["test"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {  print(userInfo) }`. If `userInfo` is printed extract the other values. Don't declare the variables as `AnyObject?`, cast them to the proper type. The supported types of an APNS payload are only a few.

Comment: yes, i have the problem with access the data,  since i try to find in stack overflow yet i can't find the right answer. @thefredelement

Comment: Sorry, it's `print(msg)`

Comment: `if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {           PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
                 if let msg = userInfo["adira"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                    print(msg)
                    }
                }`  
i try your code, while debug i can't get inside print(msg). yet the result of userInfo is the same. just can't go inside {}, and my msg still nothing @vadian

Comment: well i tried still can't @vadian

Comment: Debugging remote notifications could be quite annoying in iOS. The simulator doesn't support it. A suitable way is to paste the JSON payload string in a Playground create the dictionary with `NSJSONSerialization` and try to figure out the proper types. Apart from that I have no idea what `PFPush.handlePush()` does, maybe it changes the dictionary. Usually an APNS payload is quite easy to parse.

Comment: well i tho i don't need to use NSJSONSerialization ? if yes, i try before. but the error said " Convert fail from NSObject to NSData" 
Plus i'm using a iPhone for the testing, not simulator. @vadian
OR
I can use this fun ?
`func startParsing(data :NSData)
    {
        let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
        let header = dict.valueForKey("message") as! String
        let body = dict.valueForKey("link") as! String
    }`

But i don't know how to call ? startParsing() ?